# How to connect to network drive when I'm not home

Tags: networking, wireless, nautilus, samba

I have bought a 3 TB WD MyCloud network drive and successfully connected to it through Nautilus using Connect to Server and then smb:// followed by the IP address. I then bookmarked the different shares on the drive individually and it works like a charm when I'm at home. Of course, when I'm at work or on any other WiFi network, the bookmarks won't work, so how do I access my WD MyCloud in Ubuntu when I'm not home? Under Windows, you would use the WD MyCloud software to gain access, but of course there is no Linux version available (yet?). Any ideas? I couldn't find any existing posts, the ones I saw where only concerned to get access while you are on your home network, and that works fine.

Comment: If you have port forwarding on your router, you can do it. If not, you can try installing it with Wine (winehq.com). Otherwise, you're out of luck.

Comment: Take great care with security on this. I suggest ash (sshfs)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the public IP address assigned to your router/modem by your ISP. Most ISP assign dynamic IP's, which can change regularly. E.g. the public IP of my router changes daily at 3AM.

Some routers (like some AVM FRITZ!Box or D-Link models) offer a service which, when a new IP address is being assigned, the automatically upload this IP to a webserver. When you register for such services, you are given a URL which will then always be redirected to the IP stored on the server.

Shouldn't your router provide such a service, your ISP may. (Although I don't know any specific ISP that does.)

---

Now, after above problems are dealt with (or if you receive a static IP), we can take care of the SMB access. SMB uses port **445** by default, which means that you have to create a forwarding rule in your router, which may look like this:

```
Incoming port: 44555 # or whatever... just something else than 445 to prevent
                       automatic attacks against port 445 on random IPs
Forward to:   <smb share IP/MAC> #whatever your router offers
Forward to port: 445
```

Now you should be able to access your SMB share from all over the internet. Should you have multiple NAS's, the easiest way is to either use a different "Incoming port" for each share, or attach them all to a single host, which has to run a SMB server (although I think that could be problematic with MyCloud...)

Comment: The site, no-ip.org, gives free sub-domain dynamic DNS services. Might be useful in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So I called Comcast and static IP addresses require a business account, but they said that the IP address of my router should not change very often. So I will try to use the IP address I currently see in my router GUI. However, I really have no idea how to "create a forwarding rule in your router".  I enabled port forwarding in the menu and now there is an input mask to set this up: I chose "Service Type = TCP & UDP", "Server IP Address = 10.0.0.x" and then there are two more fields, one called "Starting Port" and one called "Ending Port". Now what?

Comment: @chris i assume starting is incoming and ending is forward. try it. if it doesn't work, swap them. So your router doesn't provide a DNS service?

Comment: The above example of 44555 and 445 gives me an error message that the Starting Port cannot be larger than the Ending Port. I set the Starting Port to a random number <445 and the Ending Port to 445 and saved it. Regarding the DNS question: there is separate item for "Dynamic DNS" in the router menu, the service provider there is called dyndns.org. I would have to enter a user name, a password, and a host name to configure it. Do I need to do that?

Comment: Ok, so I went to dyndns.org (now dyn.com) and created an account for $30 a year. I entered the necessary information into my router. How do I connect to my network drive when I'm not home, i.e., how do I use DDNS to do so?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's about forwarding all ports between (inclusive) start and end to another host. Set e.g. 44555 for both. The destination port should have its own field somewhere.

Comment: Done.  I also entered the dyndns.com account information into the router under Dynamic DNS. Still no clue how to connect through it when not home. I set up a host name of "<username>.dyndns-remote.com", so how do I use that to connect remotely? Do I even still need port forwarding in that case as I entered the local IP of the drive when I set up the DDNS?

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of your DDNS and Forwarding settings? (blacken sensitive details before publishing)